# generate random elements of which x% are zero

Tags: c, random

I know that e.g. doing this

```
if (rand() % 2 == 0) value = 0; 
else value = (float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX/(abs(rand())));
```

will generate roughly 50% zeroes and 50% other values. But are there other implementations so that I can set the sparsity arbitrarily e.g. to 42% or so.

Comment: It certainly would be easier if you were using C++.

Comment: @Unmitigated C++ is fine also

Comment: What on earth is the point of `(float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX/(abs(rand())))`? To start with, `rand()` is always non-negative, so `abs` is a no-op; however, `rand()` can return 0, so `RAND_MAX/rand()` could throw a divide-by-zero exception. Moreover, `RAND_MAX` and `rand()` are both integers, so the second division is integer division; casting the result to `(float)` doesn't change that, and is unnecessary because of the first cast to `(float)`. Finally, the two calls to `rand()` produce two different random numbers; however, that doesn't actually increase randomness.

Answer (score 2):

Since C++ 11, [`std::bernoulli_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/bernoulli_distribution) from the `<random>` header can be used.

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine e(rd());
    std::bernoulli_distribution d(0.42); // 42% probability of true
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << d(e) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting 50/50 because you're using '%2'.

If you want something like 42 out of 100 values to be non-zero, then all you need is

```
val = ( rand() % 100 < 42 ) ? rand() : 0;
```

If you need 42.5%, for instance, simply use '1000' and '425' instead.

Comment: Note that this has some bias because RAND_MAX isn't divisible by 100. There's no way to get a completely uniform distribution in standard C

Comment: One could improve this, I suppose, by calculating a 'binary' threshold that is "42%" of RAND_MAX, then gating the trenery expression by comparing against that threshold. How much refinement is desired?

Comment: @phuclv I agree that simply using modulo should be avoided due to potential bias, but your statement "There's no way to get a completely uniform distribution in standard C" is incorrect. It just takes a bit more work. [Here's a very efficient algorithm](https://lemire.me/blog/2019/06/06/nearly-divisionless-random-integer-generation-on-various-systems/), in C.

Comment: @pjs I mean using purely C standard functions without implementing the random algorithm

Answer (score 0):

1. Figure out exactly how many zeroes do you want.
2. Fill that many elements of your arry with zeroes.
3. Fill the rest with the random values (`rand() + 1` to make sure there is no unwanted zeroes).
4. Shuffle the resulting array.